# How to free space on K8s node, kubelet ImageGCFailed

Tags: kubernetes

We have a 4 node k8s 1.21.4 cluster on Ubuntu 20.04. One of the nodes has started running out of space (>80% full, the other nodes are 20%). I configured kubelet to more aggressively garbage collect unused images but this fails:

> ImageGCFailed: failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 133560354816 bytes, but freed 0 bytes

I also tried `crictl rmi --prune`. It saved some space a few days ago but now does nothing and disk usage continues to grow.

Running `crictl images` doesn't show anything big and they match the running pods. The other nodes are using far less space have much longer images lists.

```
OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS   5.4.0-153-generic   containerd://1.5.2

root@xxx:/var/lib/containerd# du -xhs *
...
264G    io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a good idea to verify if the disk space on that specific node is sufficient to host the images for the pods that are assigned to it.

It would also be good to have some sort of official position on the minimum disk size required in order to run kubernetes on a node without getting this error. Otherwise it's not clear exactly how large the volumes must be in order to be within spec for running kubernetes.

With logs you may get less info. Try to look for events of type ImageGCFailed for more details about the error. If you are using prometheus you may see if any information on container trash collection is exposed by looking at the cadvisor Prometheus metrics.

**Workaround**: 1

Use this command **crictl rmi --prune**  to clear unused images only. I suggest you clear the disk space by removing other unused files also.

**Workaround**: 2

As per the open github issue try this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71869), which may help to resolve your issue :

> **FWIW "Boot disk size in GB (per node)" was set to the minimum, 10 Gb.**

You can also refer to this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/#containers-images) for more information about the **Garbage collection of unused containers and images.**

Comment: I did do crictl rmi --prune and the machines have 300G at least. The other nodes in the cluster are similar and only on 20%. Anyway the node reached 85% (DiskPressure) and k8s evicted one of the pods and somehow this freed up the "missing" disk space.

Comment: Disk pressure causes the Kubelet daemon to scramble to recover disk space on a node by purging unnecessary images. According to the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/images/image_gc_manager.go), the Kubelet attempts to delete images based on the duration since they were last used to create a pod. If all images are in use, the Kubelet will attempt to delete them but will likely fail (this is most likely what happened to you).

Comment: Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45558) also about ImageGCFailed, unable to delete images and reclaim disk.